# Swift Calculator: operator precedence issue

Tags: swift, calculator, operator-precedence

I'm trying to develop a calculator's app in swift.

My main issue is that my calculator doesn't follow operator precedence.

For example: 1 + 1 * 8 = 9 //it's the right answer

But instead: 1 + 1 * 8 = 16 //in my calculator, which is the wrong answer

I'm following a MVC pattern. Here is my Model:

```
class CountOnMeBrain {

//MARK: - Properties
var stringNumbers: [String] = [String()]
var operators: [String] = ["+"]
var index = 0
var countOnMeDelegate: CountOnMeDelegate?
var isExpressionCorrect: Bool {
    if let stringNumber = stringNumbers.last {
        if stringNumber.isEmpty {
            if stringNumbers.count == 1 {
                countOnMeDelegate?.alertShow(title: "Zéro!", message: "Démarrez un nouveau calcul!")
            } else {
                countOnMeDelegate?.alertShow(title: "Zéro!", message: "Entrez une expression correcte!")
            }
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

var canAddOperator: Bool {
    if let stringNumber = stringNumbers.last {
        if stringNumber.isEmpty {
            countOnMeDelegate?.alertShow(title: "Zéro!", message: "Expression incorrecte!")
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

//MARK: - Methods
func addNewNumber(_ newNumber: Int) {
    if let stringNumber = stringNumbers.last {
        var stringNumberMutable = stringNumber
        stringNumberMutable += "\(newNumber)"
        stringNumbers[stringNumbers.count-1] = stringNumberMutable
    }
    updateDisplay()
}

func calculateTotal() {
    if !isExpressionCorrect {
        return
    }
    var total = Double()
    for (index, stringNumber) in stringNumbers.enumerated() {
        let number = Double(stringNumber)
        switch operators[index] {
        case "+":
            total += number!
        case "-":
            total -= number!
        case "÷":
            total /= number!
        case "x":
            total *= number!
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    countOnMeDelegate?.updateTextView(label: "\(total)")
    clear()
}

func clear() {
    stringNumbers = [String()]
    operators = ["+"]
    index = 0
}

func divide() {
    if canAddOperator {
        operators.append("÷")
        stringNumbers.append("")
        updateDisplay()
    }
}

func multiply() {
    if canAddOperator {
        operators.append("x")
        stringNumbers.append("")
        updateDisplay()
    }
}

func minus() {
    if canAddOperator {
        operators.append("-")
        stringNumbers.append("")
        updateDisplay()
    }
}

func plus() {
    if canAddOperator {
        operators.append("+")
        stringNumbers.append("")
        updateDisplay()
    }
}

func updateDisplay() {
    var text = ""
    for (index, stringNumber) in stringNumbers.enumerated() {
        // Add operator
        if index > 0 {
            text += operators[index]
        }
        // Add number
        text += stringNumber
    }
    countOnMeDelegate?.updateTextView(label: text)
}
```

}

Here is my Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var numberButtons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet var operatorButtons: UIButton!

//MARK: - Properties
var countOnMeBrain = CountOnMeBrain()

//MARK: - View Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    countOnMeBrain.countOnMeDelegate = self
}

//MARK: - Action
@IBAction func tappedNumberButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for (index, numberButton) in numberButtons.enumerated() where sender == numberButton {
        countOnMeBrain.addNewNumber(index)
    }
}

@IBAction func tappedOperatorButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        countOnMeBrain.plus()
    case 2:
        countOnMeBrain.minus()
    case 3:
        countOnMeBrain.multiply()
    case 4:
        countOnMeBrain.divide()
    case 5:
        countOnMeBrain.calculateTotal()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

I am a beginner in swift so all your precious advices are welcomed. Sorry for my poor english. Thank you.

Comment: You need to look ahead, if you have a `+` as your current operator you need to check what the next operator is before you know if you can do the addition or if you need to do another (`*,  /`) calculation first.

Comment: I didn't think about it that way. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using IBOutlet collection leads to unexpected order of buttons and you better use UIView's tag property in your Storyboard/XIB to store button's integer value and use it instead of index here:

```
@IBAction func tappedNumberButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    countOnMeBrain.addNewNumber(sender.tag)
}
```

Secondly, as per your calculateTotal method it calculates correctly.
The only incorrect thing is your method's inner logic, because it executes calculation step by step ignoring operator precedence. Unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't place for helping with algorithms. Please rewrite it according to desired logic to receive proper result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. About the IBAction, i changed it like you advised me and it works perfectly. I didn't know tag property was that good. And about the calculateTotal method, i will try to rewrite it and let you know if it works. Thank you again.

Comment: Actually, using tag property is mauveton nowadays. In terms of better architect design, you should make custom class for number buttons with @IBInspectable property of Int type which you can set directly in your XIB or Storyboard, and then use its value inside IBAction. Imagine if any opens your code. This will take time to understand tag's designation. But will be so easy once they open that custom class and see what's inside it.